# How to prove or disaprove uniform convergence of this series: $ \sum \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}+x} $

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

How to prove or disaprove uniform convergence of this series:
$$ \sum \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}+x} $$ 
on the following sets:
$ X = (0;\pi)$ and $ X = (\frac{\pi}{10};\frac{9\pi}{10})$

Comment: For the second interval you can use method of partial summation to prove uniform convergence.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.